# Find and split string at index of 2 symbols

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof

I'm doing some localization coding and I'm trying to separate possible alternatives. For example, I want to get 'en' from 'en-US' or 'en_US'. I've already worked out how to do it for the first option but I'm looking for the cleanest way to do it for both the hyphen and the underscore. I first want to check if it can be split so I don't end up with 'en' and 'en' for both the primary and alternate locales.

```
if (currLoc && currLoc.indexOf('-') > -1) {
    altLoc = currLoc.substring(0, currLoc.indexOf('-'));
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to use regular expressions.

Comment: @RhinoDevel Make that an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the string not to be arbitrary but only as `en-US` or `en_US` or empty or `en`. Try this code.

```
if(curLoc) {
    altLoc = currLoc.replace('-', '_').split('_')[0];
}
```

Actually if `currLoc` is empty string the `if(curLoc)` condition can be omitted, your `altLoc` in this case will also be empty string.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if ( currLoc ){

  if( currLoc.indexOf('-') > -1) 
    altLoc = currLoc.substring(0, currLoc.indexOf( '-' ));
  else if( currLoc.indexOf('_') > -1 )
    altLoc = currLoc.substring(0, currLoc.indexOf( '_' ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = new RegExp(/(.{2}).[-_](.{2})/gi).exec("fdgf-fed");
if (matches != null)
    altLoc  = matches[1];
```

Comment: It is preferred to add some explanation along with the answer. It will be helpful for other to understand and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'en_US';
var str1 = 'en-US';

var arr = str.replace(/[_-]/g, " ").split(" ");

arr[0] //en
arr[1] //US

var arr1 = str1.replace(/[_-]/g, " ").split(" ");

arr1[0] //en
arr1[1] //US
```

Answer (score 0):

For a regex method you can use:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^([a-z]{2})[^0-9]|[^a-z]|[^A-Z].+/g);
var result = reg.exec(text);
//result[1] <-- first group: "en" in case of "en_Us,en_US,en-US..."
```